# how to find screen coordinate in canvas to plot my own map tile in wp7 and wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

currently i'm plotting my own map tile in canvas in WP7 and i want to find screen south west lat-lon and northeast lat-lon.Like in Bing Map there LocationRect class ,but can't use this in my map tile.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to location rect of the map then check the BoundingRectangle property of the map. If you want to calculate the location rect of a tile then you need to use the formulas found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx